# How to stop Progress Bar Animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar

I would like to stop the circling inside the Progress Bar that is shown. Please tell me necessary settings to be applied either in the xml file or any methods in the code that can be used to stop this animation.
Also I have created a Progress Bar in my UI.
[The Progress bar is black in color and the animation represents the progress that  I would like to stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OmNm.png)

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:maxWidth="300dp"
       />
```

Comment: why not create your own view instead of using a progressbar? That way you can control what you want to have in your custom replacement for the progressbar.

Answer (score -1):

Using Android.Views.View.ProgressBar package

```
ProgressBar progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.pb_ProgressBar);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//Do your stuff
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this way

```
//init progress bar
ProgressDialog progressBar;

// prepare for a progress bar dialog
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
progressBar.setCancelable(true);
progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressBar.setProgress(0);
progressBar.setMax(100);

//show progress bar
progressBar.show();

//reset progress bar status
progressBarStatus = 0;

// close the progress bar dialog
progressBar.dismiss();
```

good luck

Comment: But I have used a Progress Bar and it does not contain those methods.

Comment: ProgressDialog != ProgressBar